# Sorting ls output by date in filename, in reverse order

Tags: filenames, sort, busybox

I can generate output sorted by date in "normal order" with the following command:

```
ls -A -lR | grep "^-" | sed "s/.\{43\}/&\n/" | grep -v "^-" | while read ONELINE; do if echo $ONELINE | cut -d " " -f3 | grep -o '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo $ONELINE | sed "s/.\{7\}/&$(date +%Y) /"; else echo $ONELINE; fi; done
```

Result:

```
Jan 23 2011 10:42 SOMETHING 2007.12.20.avi
Jun 26 2009 SOMETHING 2009.06.25.avi
Feb 12 2010 SOMETHING 2010.02.11.avi
Jan 29 2011 09:17 SOMETHING 2011.01.27.avi
Feb 11 2011 20:06 SOMETHING 2011.02.10.avi
Feb 27 2011 23:05 SOMETHING 2011.02.24.avi
```

How could I get the output where the newest file is at the top, like this:

```
Feb 27 2011 23:05 SOMETHING 2011.02.24.avi
Feb 11 2011 20:06 SOMETHING 2011.02.10.avi
Jan 29 2011 09:17 SOMETHING 2011.01.27.avi
Jan 23 2011 10:42 SOMETHING 2007.12.20.avi
Feb 12 2010 SOMETHING 2010.02.11.avi
Jun 26 2009 SOMETHING 2009.06.25.avi
```

Comment: @user4724: how did yuo generate the list ?

Comment: @user4724: That doesn't generate the same type of outpout for me that you have - no matter as Gilles has [the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8352/sorting-by-date/8359#8359)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214280/282382

Answer (score 31):

On most unices, `ls` has a `-t` option. From the `man` page of my Debian box:

> -t     sort by modification time

Try the following command:

`$ ls -lt`

Comment: i need it recursively, sorry

Comment: +ls -lt will list a full directory, if 1 file changes in it.

Comment: The directories and files both not sorting for me as `ls -ltr` on CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009

Comment: @ChamindaBandara we're 10 years on from this answer, so you're probably better asking a new question. Reference this one, and provide not only the command you're using but also example input and results showing how it's not working for you

Answer (score 20):

Is that a text file you're trying to sort, or are you trying to view a directory listing by date? For the latter, [use the `-t` flag to `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8352/sorting-by-date/8357#8357). For the former, see in particular the `-M` flag to GNU sort, which sorts by three-letter month name abbreviations. The following command sorts by the 3rd, 1st, 2nd and 4th columns, treating the second sort key as a month name.

```
sort -k 3 -k 1M -k2 -k4 in.txt
```

Do consider always using Japanese/ISO style dates, always in the order YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS (i.e. most significant first, constant column width). This way sorting by date is identical to a lexicographic sort.

Comment: Don't forget the leading zeroes on that date format suggestion.  This is the format I use whenever I format the string myself.

Comment: @stolenmoment You can use spaces instead of zeros if you don't mind spaces, the important point is a constant column with. `2018  5 26` works just as well as `2018 05 26` (as long as you don't go through markup that merges consecutive spaces…), what doesn't work well is `2018 5 26`.

Comment: Yeah, I reflexively avoid spaces in filenames, I'm sure you can guess why.

Answer (score 7):

I’m not sure if the functionality was in the `ls` command when the original question was asked, but now you can use the option `--full-time`.

e.g.,

```
ls -t --full-time
```

will sort with oldest time at the bottom; or if you use:

```
ls -tr --full-time
```

then it will reverse the order.

Comment: The question is about how to sort file by modification date/time. The `-t` option answers that question completely; `--full-time` isn’t really relevant.

Comment: The only thing -t option doesn't give you the year for files modified within six months where as --full-time gives you exactly that. You can also use time-style to format a date format to you liking. e.g ls -ltr --time-style+%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S

Comment: I’m not sure what your point is.  `ls -t` doesn’t give you mode and owner of the files, the host name and operating system version, or the price of tea in China, either.  `ls -t` doesn’t even display the modification date at all.  But the question isn’t about displaying file information, it’s about sorting files by modification date.  You are not contributing to the answer of the question; you are adding nice-to-know supplementary information. When you get 50 [reputation points](/help/whats-reputation), you can post that sort of information as a [comment](/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Even though `ls -t` does not show other info(mode/owner/group), adding `-l` will do. I use `ll -t` and `ll` is a common alias `ls -l` which solves the problem. For me, it is confusing at first that for changes older than 6 months, the year columns shows year, while when it's <6 months old, it's showing hours; and `--full-time` solves that. For me it's valid answer. @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'

Answer (score 1):

I like the approach of using `sort` posted in the answer by Gilles 'SO- stop being evil', but it's not quite all the way there. First, technically the OP wants reverse chronological order, not forward, and so `r` needs to be addd to the sort criterial.
So starting with `sort -k 3r -k 1Mr -k 2r -k 4r se.txt`
that would give you

```
Feb 27 2011 23:05 SOMETHING 2011.02.24.avi
Feb 11 2011 20:06 SOMETHING 2011.02.10.avi
Jan 23 2011 10:42 SOMETHING 2007.12.20.avi
Jan 29 2011 09:17 SOMETHING 2011.01.27.avi
Feb 12 2010 SOMETHING 2010.02.11.avi
Jun 26 2009 SOMETHING 2009.06.25.avi
```

But look closely and you'll note Jan 23, 2011 and Jan 29, 2011 are in the wrong order.  This is due to a subtle bug, or perhaps unclear documentation in `sort`.  An individual sort KEYDEF such as `-k2` means *starting* from field 2, not only on field 2.  It is best to also specify the stopping field as well (e.g. `-k2,2` means sorting from field 2 to field 2, i.e. only field 2).

And so

```
sort -k 3,3r -k 1,1Mr -k 2,2r -k 4,4r
```

yields the correct results.
(I was able to get this to work by setting only some of the stop fields in the KEYDEFs, but I don't know which are necessary and why, so it seems best to specify them all.  Well, except maybe the last one, but then in the OP input file there are some records with 4 fields and some with 5 so the 4th field is not always the final field)

Comment: It's not a bug, it's as clearly specified in the manuals of most sort implementations and in the POSIX specification. See also [Sort based on the third column](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/104525)

Comment: I read GNU and BSD man pages. It is not clear at all to me why the first sort in my post fails.  (Ignoring the 2 records that are only 4 fields).,  it sorts 1st time by year-field then time-field then other things; 2nd time, using month criteria, by month-field, then day field, then time-field, then other things; 3rd time by day-field, then year-field, then time field, then other things, 4th time by other things.  My reading of man page is that the day fields (col 2) get correctly sorted in the 3rd pass, and nothing should happen in the 4th (col 4+) pass to knock them out of order.

Answer (score 1):

This will list all files **recursively** with `ls` output and **reverse sorted** by **modified time** (mtime):

```
find -print0 -type f directory_path | xargs -0 ls -ltr
```

Peform the search more quickly with [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)

```
fd -0 -t f directory_path | xargs -0 ls -ltr
```

Comment: (`s/--type/-type/`)  That only works if file paths don't contain whitespace nor quotes nor backslashes and if the list of files is small enough that `ls` is invoked only once.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Answer improved to address special chars. And as for `ls` invocation, the argument length limit on the vast majority of systems is 2Mib which means that even for an average full path of 100 characters, we still got a 20000 files batch. I believe that will be sufficient for >99% of people coming here.

Comment: Should be `find directory_path -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 ls -ltrd` (wrong order of arguments for `find`; without `-r`, you'd end up with the current directory listed if `find` found no regular (`-type f`) files; `-d` not strictly necessary as `ls` should not be passed any directory files, but good habit to have when passing file lists to `ls`)

Answer (score 0):

With the standard `-t` option, `ls` will sort files (given as arguments or found in the contents of directories passed argument) by modification time from newest to oldest.

With the `-R` option, `ls` enters a recursive mode, but it still lists the contents of each directory separately, so while each directory listing will be listed by modification time, you won't get a notion of the relative time of files between different directories. The files will also not be listed with their full path.

To list files recursively with their full paths, ordered by time, you'd need to pass all of them by path to `ls`. You could do it with:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name . -o -name '.*' -prune -o -exec ls -ltd {} +
```

(`-name . -o -name '.*' -prune -o` with `LC_ALL=C` to exclude hidden files, like `ls` does by default without `-a`/`-A` when it lists the contents of directories itself)

But that will break as soon as there are so many files that `find` needs to call `ls` several times to work around the `execve()` limit on the size or argument+environment that can be passed to a command, where you'll end up with several independent sorted lists.

To address that, you'd need to sort the list outside of `ls` and pass the list to those several invocations of `ls -ld`. With the `zsh` shell and a `xargs` that supports the `-0` and `-r` option, that can be done with:

```
print -rNC1 -- **/*(Nom) | xargs -r0 ls -ltd --
```

If your `ls` supports the non-standard `-U` option to skip sorting, you can use that in place of `-t` as zsh has already sorted the list with its `om` (`o`rder by `m`odification time) glob qualifier. Add the `D` glob qualifier if you want hidden files to be included.

With the GNU implementations of `find`, `ls`, `cut` and `sort`, you can also do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name . -o -name '.*' -prune -o -printf '%T@\t%P\0' |
  sort -rzn |
  cut -zf2- |
  xargs -r0 ls -lUd --
```

Answer (score -4):

recursive (`R`) and pause (`|more`)

```
ls -ltR |more
```